# Stream PDF to iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a pdf stream and would like to stream it right to the iframe. I know you can give an iframe a source file, but dont know if iframe can take in a stream instead and show pdf. Thankx

Comment: Can do this with struts2 (java) please be specific in the desired tool set.

Comment: Hi! I am using C# and asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an aspx page that binarywrites the PDF the response stream. Set this aspx page to the iframe.